# checkbox functionality in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple text boxes in a row with five columns, and those are disabled by default and should be enabled if I check on a checkbox corresponding to that particular row. With the following code I am able to enable all the textboxes by checking the first check box only. But I need an individual operation for every row.

My controller code:

```
$scope.checkEnable = function () {
    console.log($('#check').prop('checked'));
    $scope.enableText = !$('#check').prop('checked');
};
```

html:

```
<div class="row item-head" ng-repeat="item in area track by $index">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 check-box">
        <input type="checkbox" id='check' ng-model="check" ng-change="checkEnable()" /> {{item.servicename}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="enableText" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="enableText" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="enableText" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="enableText" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="enableText" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't even need controller (and of course avoid using jQuery for such things). You just use ngDisabled like `ng-disabled="check"`:

```
<div class="row item-head" ng-repeat="item in area track by $index">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 check-box">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"> {{item.servicename}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="check">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="check">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="check">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="check">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="check">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with your modification I am able to disable the textboxes when I check the checkbox, but what exactly I need is, by default textboxes should be disabled and when I check the checkbox then only the textboxes should be enable.

Comment: Oh, then it needs to be `<input type="text" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check">`, `ng-disabled="!check"` for each input.

Comment: When I checked the check box, I can able to enter the values in the text boxes but I need to empty the text boxes when I unchecked the check box. Can you please help me out for this?